# Azure SQL handling table locks for huge inserts

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure-sql-database

In my application, I have a windows service (hosted as quartz on azure web) which runs after a particular time and reads a file and inserts data. The data can be of any length so the type in DB is "text". All records are inserted in one table.
Problem is that the service might run in parallel and try insert the records in table at the same time. Since the data might be huge and I want to have performance also, I want to make the service run in parallel. I am using EF 6.0 and LINQ. Is there a possible way to not lock the table and insert huge data.

Note: Bulk insert might not work as the data type to insert have 'text' as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that there is one column of type "text" in your table and nothing else. Based on the above assumptions, I would think that there would not be fundamental semantic problems if you want to run this in parallel.

There are a couple of ways of doing this:

1. use SqlBulkCopy class with row batches. This will copy batches of rows and load them into the table. This can be done in parallel.
2. use a temporary staging table for each service, and then run INSERT INTO SELECT for each staging table. The INSERT portion will be in serial because it will take an X lock on the table, but this may be faster than loading one row by another.

Neither of these methods uses EF 6.0 and LINQ, but they will get the job done.

Hope this helps!